# I can't get max from counted value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.Table t1 has columns(ID,Name) and t2 has columns(ID,Date,Time)...I want to run a query like

```
select t1.Name,t2.ID,count(t2.Date)as Present_Days,MAX(x) as total 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(t2.ID) AS x FROM t2 GROUP BY ID) as y 
from t1 
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID 
group by Name
```

When I remove this line "MAX(x) as total FROM (SELECT COUNT(t2.ID) AS x FROM t2 GROUP BY ID) as y" from query, it gives the result..but the original query doesnot work...What can be done to run this query.

Comment: What should be the result of the query?

Comment: I mean,  the query you showed is syntactically wrong,  and we can help you writing valid query: but to help you writing the "right"  query you need to tell us something more of what the tables represent and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Stan . . . Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The query really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong FROM (  )  dinamic table  and two FROM instead of a proper inner join  could be you are looking for something like this

```
  select 
       t1.Name
      ,t2.ID
      ,count(t2.Date) as Present_Days
      ,MAX(y.x) as total 
  FROM ( 
          SELECT t2.ID, COUNT(t2.ID) AS x 
          FROM t2 
          GROUP BY ID
        )  y 
  INNER  JOIN  t1 on y.ID = t1.ID
  INNER JOIN t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID 
  group by t1.Name, t2.ID
```

and if you need another column named time from t2 you could use

```
  select 
       t1.Name
      ,t2.ID
      ,count(t2.Date) as Present_Days
      ,MAX(y.x) as total 
      , t2.`time`
  FROM ( 
          SELECT t2.ID, COUNT(t2.ID) AS x 
          FROM t2 
          GROUP BY ID
        )  y 
  INNER  JOIN  t1 on y.ID = t1.ID
  INNER JOIN t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID 
  group by t1.Name, t2.ID, t2.`time`
```

do the fact that you are join the table t2 you can directly select t2.time in the main select ..

Anyway you could select the t2.time also from the subselect  adding this column properly in subquery and using a proper alias  like column my_time in the sample below

```
  select 
       t1.Name
      ,t2.ID
      ,count(t2.Date) as Present_Days
      ,MAX(y.x) as total 
      , y.my_time
  FROM ( 
          SELECT t2.ID, t2.`time` as my_time, COUNT(t2.ID) AS x 
          FROM t2 
          GROUP BY ID
        )  y 
  INNER  JOIN  t1 on y.ID = t1.ID
  INNER JOIN t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID 
  group by t1.Name, t2.ID, t2.`time`
```

and for absent_days you can use   a difference between the two column involved  (no alias)

```
  select 
       t1.Name
      ,t2.ID
      ,count(t2.Date) as Present_Days
      ,MAX(y.x) as total 
      , t2.`time`
      , MAX(y.x) - count(t2.Date) as Absent_Days
  FROM ( 
          SELECT t2.ID, COUNT(t2.ID) AS x 
          FROM t2 
          GROUP BY ID
        )  y 
  INNER  JOIN  t1 on y.ID = t1.ID
  INNER JOIN t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID 
  group by t1.Name, t2.ID, t2.`time`
```

if you need filter by name  you can

```
  select 
       t1.Name
      ,t2.ID
      ,count(t2.Date) as Present_Days
      ,MAX(y.x) as total 
      , t2.`time`
      , MAX(y.x) - count(t2.Date) as Absent_Days
  FROM ( 
          SELECT t2.ID, COUNT(t2.ID) AS x 
          FROM t2 
          GROUP BY ID
        )  y 
  INNER  JOIN  t1 on y.ID = t1.ID
  INNER JOIN t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID 
  where   t1.Name =  'somename' 
  group by t1.Name, t2.ID, t2.`time`
```

Comment: Shouldn't t2.id be added to the group by? (however it was like this also in the original query)

Comment: It should have been `select 
           t1.Name
          ,t2.ID
          ,count(t2.Date) as Present_Days
          ,MAX(y.x) as total 
      FROM ( 
              Select t2.id, 
               COUNT(t2.ID) AS x 
              FROM t2 
              GROUP BY ID
            )  y 
      INNER JOIN t1 on y.ID = t1.ID
      INNER JOIN t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID 
      group by t1.Name, t2.id`

Comment: Thanks all for your help

Comment: @scaisEdge there are still a couple of things that make this query "non valid SQL".  The sub query doesn't start with "SELECT" and there is a "INNER" without "JOIN". You can compare the SQL you wrote with the one I put in a previous comment.

Comment: if i have to select time from t2 where show i write for time??

Comment: @stan   explain better i don't see column time in the query .. .. you need to select another column from t2 named time and wnat to know where this column should be placed for a right select ?

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks,  but I just highlighted some SQL issues of your query.  I still don't know exactly what's needed from the OP,  so I am not going to answer. Just helped you in your attempt to answer him.

Comment: i want to select t2.time along with the query given up ...where should i add time in the query?

Comment: @Insac  you are very kind I hope I can repay your kindness soon

Comment: @Stan  . i have update the asnwer adding a query with time too.. hope is what you are looking for ..

Comment: could u plez answer me

Comment: can it be put after max()?? if yes where??

Comment: now lastly, if i hav to select absent_days from present_days and total....what should be done to the query??

Comment: @stan    first  i don't know your schema and i can't eval the meaning and rule of absent_days  and present_days  .. (flat column .. or others)  and then i can't give you a proper answer .. second .. in stackoverfllow is not correct changing (or extending) the question time by time .. . if you need new answer you should post a new question properly  described.. eventaully commenting me the new  link .. so . if my answer is correct please mark it as accepted and for the others  question post a new one

Comment: Sorry but my question is from same schemas...In the query there is count as present_days and max() as total so all i want to do is substract present_days from total and find out required absent_days and select the absent_days allong with others as shown above in the query

Comment: @scaisEdge if i need the record of a particular Name(ie; where Name='somename') from above query, what would be the code?

Comment: @Stan   Post a proper new question and comment me the link  .. at first look the simplest way  is the use of having ..

Comment: @scaisEdge sir do i have to post the same question to get the required answer? it would be helpful if u answer where should i add where Name='somename' in the query.